# RadioGroup.clearCheck() not working in case of dynamically created radio buttons

Tags: android, onclick, radio-button

In my app,i am creating radio buttons dynamically and want to uncheck all other radio buttons when one of them is checked.For this purpose,i am using RadioGroup.clearCheck() but it is not working at all.This is the code:

```
for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
            {
                rbi = new RadioButton(context);

                rb1 = new RadioGroup(context);
                rb1.addView(rbi);


                nameOfFile = files[i].getName();
                rbi.setText(nameOfFile);
                ll.addView(rb1);

                rbi.setOnClickListener(
                        new RadioButton.OnClickListener()
                        {  
                            @Override  
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {                                   

                                rb1.clearCheck();
                                rbi.setChecked(true);

                            }
```

Please help me.Even the alternate solutions for achieving the goal will be welcomed.Thanks in advance.

Comment: They all get checked when you check one?

Comment: You are AFAIK not supposed to do `setOnClickListener` for the `RadioButton`s since that is managed by the `RadioGroup` already which would inform you via `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: @Bigflow none of the radiobutton gets unchecked when i call rb1.clearcheck()

Comment: @zapl Can you please elaborate by giving few lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a lot of `RadioGroup`s with just 1 `RadioButton` inside. That is probably not what you want. A `RadioGroup` needs to contain several `RadioButton`s so you can select an active button inside the list. See code below

```
// create 1 RadioGroup, add it to the layout
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(context);
ll.addView(rg);
// add several RadioButtons to the RadioGroup
for (int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
    String nameOfFile = files[i].getName();
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(context);
    rb.setId(i); // assign an id
    rb.setText(nameOfFile);
    rg.addView(rb); // add to group
}
// do something when user checks a button
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // user selected files[checkedId].getName();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try (with System.out.println("test");) or something, if it even gets into the clearing part? Would test that first.
This is what zapl means

```
rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
         new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                 public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rb1,
                        int checkedId) {
                        Log.v("Selected", "New radio item selected: " + checkedId);
                        }
          });
```

if that works, then you can try this:

```
 if (rbi.isChecked()){
    rb1.clearCheck();
    rbi.setChecked(true);
    }
```